# downloading tweets automatically to json output in

Tags: r

I am very new to downloading tweets from R. I want to download tweets automatically in a day and I wrote the following code

```
`key <- "xx"
cons_secret <- "xx"
token <- "xx"
access_secret <- "xx"
my_token <- setup_twitter_oauth(key, cons_secret, token, access_secret)

BIST <- "BIST"
stream_tweets( "BIST", timeout = 60,
  parse = FALSE, token=my_token)`
```

this code did not work,

I got this error 
`Error in readRDS(x) : error reading from connection`

I also want to download them to json output in.
Is my code true? How can I handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe in what way it does not work. Eg. if you get an error what is the error?

Comment: I editted question, thanks for reminding it to me.